# Formatar String do formato moeda para Number com casas decimais

Tags: javascript

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho o valor de um Input que está recebendo o valor em real, por exemplo:

```
"2,55"
```

Preciso converter esse valor para um formato de number com as mesmas casas decimais e a virgula. Não pode ser: 2.55 por exemplo, pois a API está configurada para receber um number, no formato:

```
2,55
```

Já utilizei de algumas funções que vi por aqui, porém todas a saída é uma string, se alguém poder me ajudar, agradeço!

Comment: Os números em javascript não podem ter vírgulas. Tem que converter para string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para converter para um valor em string para número pode utilizar por exemplo [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) ou [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

No seu caso como é um valor com decimais pode usar o `parseFloat()`, mas tem um detalhe, o valor deve usar "." como separador decimal, se fizer diretamente o parse com a tua string não vai converter corretamente:

```js
console.log(parseFloat("2,55"));
```

Para converter corretamente precisa então substituir a "," por ".", e pode fazer isso usando a função `replace()`:

```js
let varlorString = "2,55";
let valorComPonto = "2,55".replace(",",".");
console.log(parseFloat(valorComPonto));
```

Comment: Entendi, de fato quando eu utilizava o parseFloat() diretamente com a virgula, ele sempre quebrava as casas decimais. Fico agradecido pela resposta, pois não sabia que não era possível essa conversão com parseFloat com virgula.